# What to do when the AVD is HUGE and is taller than the screen

Tags: android-emulator

I am setting up my environment in Eclipse to do some development for the Galaxy Tab 7", and I have a problem with my Android Virtual Device (AVD).

If I set my target for:

> GALAXY Tab Addon - API Level 8

and the Skin to:

> Default (GALAXY Tab)

using the `Edit AVD` button in the `Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager` menu, when I run my `Hello Android` app, the AVD window is so huge as to be useless (note, I also think the actual emulated Tab is taller than the window itself...). See screen capture below, in which you see top of the screen to bottom (w/taskbar). My screen size is `1680 x 1050`.

Now, if I switch the target to:

> Android 2.2 - API Level 8

and the Skin to:

> Default (WVGA800)

the AVD window is a reasonable size, but I imagine this is because it's emulating a phone-size device, not the 7" Tab. I am needing to target the 7" Tab though, so that's not really an option for me.

Short of increasing my desktop resolution, does anybody know how to get this window to open up in maybe a 75% size? Or some other workaround?

[image: AVD Too Big]

Comment: Why don't you run it in landscape mode? Portrait is not the default orientation for tablets, even if the Android SDK defaults to portrait.  I'm also wondering if you can cut out the body of the device and set the view to screen-only; the Tab's screen is 1024x600, so it should fit your screen like that while in portrait mode.

Comment: @Matthew Read - Those are great ideas (especially since my apps will probably require landscape anyway). I'll give them a shot when I get home later and let you know if they work. :)

Comment: @Matthew Read - Both of your suggestions work independently, as well as there is an option when using a specific resolution to scale it to a certain size. However, now the keyboard and other stuff that was to the right is gone. Do you know how to get this back, or is this tied to the skin?

Comment: No idea, I haven't actually used it :)

Comment: @Matthew Read - I found [this site](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/), which helped (although I haven't really figured out what I want to do yet). If you post your first comment as an answer, I'll upvote and mark it as *the* answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you run it in landscape mode? Portrait is not the default orientation for tablets, even if the Android SDK defaults to portrait. I'm also wondering if you can cut out the body of the device and set the view to screen-only; the Tab's screen is 1024x600, so it should fit your screen like that while in portrait mode.

Comment: Others: See comments under the question for more information. :)